# How to use IResultSetMapper in Enterprise Library?

Tags: database, enterprise-library

I need to map table record with foreign key with another table using Enterprise Library.
Please provide any sample code using IResultSetMapper. I am currently using IRowMapper to map columns and object property is not mapping.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637348/using-microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-data-iresultsetmappert

Comment: Thank You @RandyLevy , I have used WithFunc and mapped child object from their